# Execute fadeIn callback only once

Tags: jquery

I did this small example to simulate my problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var callback = function(){
    output.innerHTML += '<br>Fade example finished !!';
  };
  $('.fade').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn(callback);
});
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fade">Fade example</div>
<div class="fade">Fade example</div>
<div class="fade">Fade example</div>
<div id="output">Output: </div>
```

As you can see, the fadeIn callback executes once per div.

However I want it to run only once for all `'.fade'` elements.

Is there any property I can set, so the callback is executed only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use "when" in this scenario.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var callback = function(){
    output.innerHTML += '<br>Fade example finished !!';
  };
  $.when($('.fade').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn()).then(function () {
 callback();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `one` may be useful in this particular case.

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element per event type.

From jQuery documentation.

Read more jQuery documentation about one here
http://api.jquery.com/one/